# TikZ > Is it possible to use the identifier of coordinates as string?

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, loops, coordinates

I am drawing pictures with TikZ using loops, for instance `\foreach \point in {(i),(j),(k)} {...}`. Is it possible to use the name of the coordinates as string to label a node?

I'd like to use `\node at \point {Vertex (n)}` where `n` should be replaced with, for instance, `i`.

Many thanks in advance!

---

Minimal Working Example

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,DIV11]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
    \coordinate (i) at (0,0); \coordinate (j) at (1,1);
    \foreach \point in {(i),(j)}
    {
        \node at \point {Vertex (n)};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The Nodes should be labeld correlating to their identifiers, therefore (i) and (j). The reason for doing this is, is that this should be included in a complex drawing.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: See if `\node at \point {Vertex \point};` gives what you like to obtain.

Comment: TikZ is loaded in LaTeX with `\usepackage{tikz}`. The usage of `\include` in the preamble is pretty wrong; please, check the documentation of LaTeX.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Of course! I got that wrong when creating the minimal working example and didn't notice although Overleaf printed a warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly than you looking for one of the following results:

[image]

or

[image]

Both images are generated by:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,
               multi,
               tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
vrtx/.style = {circle, draw, fill=gray!30, inner sep=2pt}
                    ]
    \coordinate (i) at (0,0); \coordinate (j) at (1,1);
    \foreach \point in {(i),(j)}
    {
        \node[vrtx,label=left:Vertex \point] at \point {};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (i) at (0,0); \coordinate (j) at (1,1);
    \foreach \point in {(i),(j)}
    {
        \node at \point {Vertex \point};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Thanks! To exclude the braces I use `\foreach \point in {i,j}` and later on `\node at (\point) {Vertex \point};`.

Comment: This I guessing that can be possible wish, but I was not sure if you interested for this, and solution is simple. As I see, you manage it yourself. Happy TeXing!